# Class change not visible with mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing some code with w3.css inspired by Material Design. I'm trying to make a card such that the shadow size changes on mouseover. The code I'm using looks like:

```
  <div class="w3-card-4"
  onMouseOver="this.style.className='w3-card-16';"
  onMouseOut="this.style.className='w3-card-4';">
    <a href="pages/gameoflife.html"> <img src="images/gameoflife.gif"></img> </a>
  </div>
```

Whenever I mouse over though, the appearance doesn't change. I can see that the class name changes, because if I add `console.log(this.style.className)` it prints the correct class. Why is the change not visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `className` attribute applies to the Element, not to its `style` attribute:

`ELEMENT.className = "..."`, not: `ELEMENT.style.className = "..."`

```
<div class="w3-card-4"
     onMouseOver="this.className='w3-card-16';"
     onMouseOut="this.className='w3-card-4';">
    <a href="pages/gameoflife.html"> <img src="images/gameoflife.gif"></img> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay  Just leave a comment if you need more help

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!